# What're those things for in Hector - Badge of Carnage?

Tags: hector-badge-of-carnage

At the beginning of the game, I got the ticket in the police station. Later I found the "Who care" badge from the tourist booth. What're they for? Any secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this walkthrough](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=57636):

> You get a "Who Cares" button that has
>   absolutely no use in the game.

The ticket also appears to have no in-game use whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you. I think puzzle games shouldn't have no-use items like them! They make us confused.

Comment: It should be noted that no use has been found for the bus ticket _yet_, though several people have scoured the game looking for a use. Nothing has come up.

Comment: LOL, hope there will be some use of them, or these people will be very disappointed!